# Resolving Invalid Column Type in JSP

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I have the following database:

```
1)Emp_master

EMPID Number primary key
FNAME Varchar2
LNAME Varchar2
GENDER Varchar2
DOB Date
DEPTID Number

2)Emp_Leave

LEAVETYPE   Varchar2(30)
DATEFROM    Date
DATETO  Date
NO_OF_DAYS  Number
STATUS  Varchar2(10)
ENO Number(5)
```

Now when I execute the below code in JSP, I am getting the error:

> invalid column type: getDate not implemented for class.oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CNumberAccessor

This is the code:

```
eno=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Eno"));
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "HR","HR");

Statement st=con.createStatement();

        String qry1="select leavetype datefrom,dateto,no_of_days,status from emp_leave where eno="+eno;
        ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery(qry1);
        rs1.next();
        type=rs1.getString(1);
        dt_from=rs1.getDate(2);
        dt_to=rs1.getDate(3);
        days=rs1.getInt(4);
        status=rs1.getString(5);


        String qry2="select fname,lname from emp_master where empid="+eno;
        ResultSet rs2=st.executeQuery(qry2);
        rs2.next();
        fname=rs2.getString(2);
        lname=rs2.getString(3);
```

I can't seem to figure out why is it throwing the error. I have declared `dt_from` and `dt_to`  as a Date datatype variable.

Comment: Which driver version are you using? (The number in the file name is **not** the _driver_ version, it's the targeted Java version)

Comment: There is a missing comma in the first query. Also, don't put JDBC code in JSPs, and use prepared statements. The indices used to get fname and lname are wrong, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the query with the getters:
`select leavetype datefrom,dateto,no_of_days,status from emp_leave where ...`

```
 type=rs1.getString(1);  // gets: leavetype datefrom 
 dt_from=rs1.getDate(2); // gets: dateto
 dt_to=rs1.getDate(3);  // gets: no_of_days (of type: Number ) <= this throws the error !!!
 days=rs1.getInt(4);  // gets: status (of type: Varchar)
 status=rs1.getString(5); // gest: ???
```

Most likely there is missing comma in the SELECT statament between `leavetype` and `datefrom`.

In SQL the below expression in the SELECT clasue:

```
SELECT somename someanothername FROM .....
```

is a shorcut for:

```
   SELECT somename AS someanothername FROM .....
```

This SELECT retrieves only one column named `somename` and renames it into `someanothername`